# Supervision of formal proof of cut rule

Tags: proof-verification, logic

The Cut rule states that from the formulas $(F \to G)$ and $(G \to H)$
we can derive the formula $(F \to H)$.

My task is to give a formal proof for this rule. I'm not sure if my proof is formally and logically correct, so I'm asking for supervision.

$$
\begin{alignat*}{}
1.&\Gamma\vdash(F\to G)&\text{Premise 1}\\
2.&\Gamma\vdash(G\to H)&\text{Premise 2}\\
3.&\Gamma\,\cup\{F\}\vdash F&\text{Assume $F$}\\
4.&\Gamma\,\cup\{F\}\vdash(F\to G)&\text{Apply monotonicity to 1}\\
5.&\Gamma\,\cup\,\{F\}\vdash G&\text{Apply $\to$ elimination to 3 and 4}\\
6.&\Gamma\,\cup\,\{F\}\vdash(G\to H)&\text{Apply monotonicity to 2}\\
7.&\Gamma\,\cup\,\{F\}\vdash H&\text{Apply $\to$ elimination to 5 and 6}\\
8.&\Gamma\vdash(F\to H)&\text{Apply $\to$ introduction to 7}\\
\end{alignat*}
$$

*Note: This is exercise 1.9 from 1st edition of A First Course in Logic.*

Comment: I think that step 3 is justified by Monotonicty rule and $\to$-elimination.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I'll fix it.

Comment: And you need an additional step 6. $\Gamma \vdash (F \to H)$ by $\to$-introduction.

Comment: What is "reversed $\to$ introduction"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's not a real rule and should be rather qoted. It logically make sense to me, but formally it will be maybe sequence of assumption/monotonicity and $\to$ elimination.

Comment: Does your Conditional Elimination rule actually require the sequents to have the same assumption set?  $$\begin{split}\Gamma\cup\Delta&\vdash \phi\to\psi\\\Gamma\cup\Delta&\vdash\phi\\\hline\Gamma\cup\Delta&\vdash\psi \end{split}\quad\textsf{versus}\quad\begin{split}\Gamma&\vdash \phi\to\psi\\\Delta&\vdash\phi\\\hline\Gamma\cup\Delta&\vdash\psi \end{split}$$If it does, okay, otherwise the monotonicity steps are redundant.